# Add variable labels within mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am in the process of reworking some old code in order to facilitate learning the `tidyverse`. In the previous code I would make new variables derrived from present variables, and I would give these new variables a label attribute using `label` from the `Hmisc` package. This would look like this.

```
library(Hmisc)

iris$new <- ifelse(iris$Species == 'setosa', 1, 0)
label(iris$new) <- "New Variable"
```

which gives this result

```
> str(iris$new)
 'labelled' num [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "New Variable"
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to apply this same type of thing within a mutate call.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `result <- iris %>% mutate(New.Variable = ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 1, 0))`

Comment: No, I know how to create the variable using mutate. I am trying to figure out how to manipulate the variable attribute `label` after I have created the variable within mutate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `structure()`:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(new = structure(ifelse(iris$Species == 'setosa', 1, 0), label = "New Variable"))

label(iris$new)
#[1] "New Variable"
```

Comment: Yes, this does what I was looking for, and it can be chained together within a mutate call like so, `iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(iris$Species == 'setosa', 1, 0) %>% structure(label = "New Variable"))` which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, bit you can also do

```
iris %>% 
mutate(new =`label<-`(ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 1, 0), value="New Variable"))
```

This won't bypass any of the checks that `label<-` does by default that the structure would skip. You can also wrap this in a function to make it cleaner.

```
labelled <- function(x, label) {
  label(x) <- label
  x
}
iris %>% 
  mutate(new =labelled(ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 1, 0), "New Variable"))
# or
iris %>% 
  mutate(new =ifelse(Species == 'setosa', 1, 0) %>% labelled("New Variable"))
```